# How to find recently edited python files using a regex, called from a makefile

Tags: regex, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to get the following recipe to work:

```
recent_py:
    find . -cmin -60 | egrep '*.py$\'
```

And am getting the following error when calling it:

```
> make recent_py
find . -cmin -60 | egrep '*.py'
```

The error being that the `$` is ignored, so the regex used isn't the regex that I intended (so `.pyc` files are matched for example)

How can I edit the regex so that it works as I would expect it to when called from the terminal?

## edit

updating to

```
recent_py:
    find . -cmin -60 | grep -E '\.py$'
```

gives error:

```
> make recent_py
find . -cmin -60 | grep -E '\.py
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make: *** [Makefile:81: recent_py] Error 2
```

## answer

```
recent_py:
    find . -cmin -60 | grep -E '\.py$$'
```

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60036/meaning-of-asterisk-in-grep

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep -E` instead (as `egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent`):

```
find . -cmin -60 | grep -E '\.py$'
```

Or via `find`'s param `-regex`:

```
find . -cmin -60 -regex '.*\.py'
```

Comment: Using `grep -E` as there gives an error - i've edited the OP to highlight this